# add text to iframe inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, input

Please help me with an Iframe trigger.

How to put the value inside the input field of the iframe?
I believe the problem lives because of the layout levels.

(the iframe is placed on my own site as html)

**My Iframe:**

```
<form id="form">
<div id="root">
<iframe id="lev-iframe">
<html>
<form id="form">
<fieldset class="fields">      
  <div class="full">
  <div class="part">
     <input class="uniqueclass" name="uniquename" type="text" value="" />
  </div></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
//tested #root, #form, #lev-iframe; nothing seems to work for me...

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("load", function() {

$('#root').trigger('setFieldValue', {
name: 'uniquename',
value: 'myvalue'

})  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: This code is bizarre.

Comment: Haha I'm sorry. Hopefully you mean the iframe code and not the trigger. I think i'm close to solve it, but currently it does nothing for me.

Comment: I think you need to learn the basics of HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define IFRAME like you do in your example by adding HTML inside of IFRAME tags. It has to either point to another page that has this HTML:

```
<iframe id="lev-iframe" src="other_page.html"></iframe>
```

or fill it with HTML programmaticaly, for example:

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="lev-iframe"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
//This code will add input box to the iframe above
var doc = $("#lev-iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;
var $body = $('body',doc);
$body.html('<input class="uniqueclass" id="uniquename" type="text" value="" />');
```

Once you have a valid IFRAME it's a simple matter of accessing the element you need:

```
$("#lev-iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('uniquename').value = 'myvalue';
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wbwCu/**

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Is it not possible to print a value to a inputbox (setFieldValue) instead of adding a whole new inputfield?

Comment: Adding the whole input field was just an example of programmatically creating IFRAME content - you dont have to do it. If you define IFRAME's HTML via "SRC =" like in the first example, then all you need to set the value is that last line of code.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, I managed to update the value and finally intergrated the new inputfield.

Comment: @yurij http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985005/how-to-run-js-code-after-form-iframe-loaded-and-place-custom-value-in-input any luck about this